# Do I need to tell jslint about functions that have not yet been defined inside another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this:

```
function dialog($link) {
    "use strict";

   function doDialogAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html'
        })
            .done(onDialogDone)
            .fail(onDialogFail);
   }

   function onDialogDone(data) {
        content = data;
   // ... 
   }
}
```

jslint complains that the onDialogDone has not yet been defined. Do I really need to define it as a global at the top of my code. The reason I am asking is because I don't think the function onDialogDone is a global. It's just a function not yet defined within the outer function.

Also am I correct in saying that a function defined this way should not have a semicolon at the end after the last curly brace?

Answer (score 0):

`jslint` complains about many things because its author believes they are bad style, not because they are intrinsically incorrect.

In this case, your function definition will be hoisted to the top of the scope and is perfectly valid code.

On the semicolon question, there is no harm in including one.  The ES5 specification does not require it, though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define it as a global, just define it before the ajax call. Which in fact doesn't matter for two reasons:

- the function definition is [hoisted](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/) anyway
- the ajax call is asynchronous so the code below will execute before the callback is fired

Nevertheless, it's good to have jslint-compliant code but it's not a matter of life and death ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine. However, since `JSLint` uses a [*Pratt Parser (Top Down Operator Precedence)*](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) to analyze your code, when it sees `onDialogDone` for the first time, it complains because it was not defined yet.

To prevent it from complaining, just move the function to the top. This way, `JSLint` will parse the definition first, and when it sees `.done(onDialogDone)`, it will **know** what the symbol `onDialogDone` refers to.

```
function onDialogDone(data) {
  // ...
}

function doDialogAjax() {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I added /*global onDialogDone, onDialogFail, submitHandler*/  However now jslint complains that onDialogDone is an unused variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: @SamanthaJ: Don't use `global` for functions. To fix the original issue, all you need to do is push the function `onDialogDone` to the top, so that JSLint picks its definition before its invocation. But again, note that your code is perfectly fine. It's just that JSLint does not use a JavaScript interpreter, but a top-down parser, thus in your current code order, when it first detects the symbol `onDialogDone`, it was not yet defined.